# Regex to extract only IPv4 addresses from text

Tags: php, regex, ip, spf

I've tried to extract only IP addresses from the the given example input, but it extracts some text with it. Here's my code:

```
$spfreccord="v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:nl2go.com include:smtproutes.com include:smtpout.com ip4:46.163.100.196 ip4:46.163.100.194 ip4:85.13.135.76 ~all";

 $regexIpAddress = '/ip[4|6]:([\.\/0-9a-z\:]*)/';        
 preg_match($regexIpAddress, $spfreccord, $ip_match);
 var_dump($ip_match);
```

I'm looking to match only the IPv4 IP address `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` in each column of the table, but it looks like that the `$regexIpAddress` is not correct.

Can you please help me find the correct regex to extract only the IPv4 IP addresses? Thanks.

Comment: Tried `/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/`?

Comment: yeh it work just fine but one little problem is that i cannot extract cidr class
v=spf1 ip4:205.201.128.0/20 ip4:198.2.128.0/18 ?all

is it possible to extract the cidr 205.201.128.0/20

Comment: Then change it to: `/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{2})?/`

Comment: Hi @Will  you answer is working fine but i don't need to extract the text "ip4" with the ips, 
Hi @Thamilan your answer is working good for me but one problem is that i cannot extract classes cidr like this `198.2.128.0/18`
so please if there is something to add to my ipregex to extract also cidr like this example  `198.2.128.0/18`
thanks all

Comment: @sala.eddi mine doesn't extract the text, just the IPs. Look at the output in my example.

Comment: Hi Will yes but it extract reccord like this ip4:94.176.182.0
i don't need to extract  ip4 beside i need to extract cidr classes like this 
198.2.128.0/18, 
Thanks any way that was very helpful from you 
HI @Thamilan your answer is the good answer for my question bcause it give me classes and unique ips address thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{2})?/
```

So for this:

```
$spfreccord="v=spf1 include:amazonses.com include:nl2go.com include:smtproutes.com include:smtpout.com ip4:46.163.100.196 ip4:46.163.100.194 ip4:85.13.135.76 cidr class v=spf1 ip4:205.201.128.0/20 ip4:198.2.128.0/18 ~all";

 $regexIpAddress = '/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{2})?/';        
 preg_match_all($regexIpAddress, $spfreccord, $ip_match);
 var_dump($ip_match);
```

Gives:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "46.163.100.196"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "46.163.100.194"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "85.13.135.76"
    [3]=>
    string(16) "205.201.128.0/20"
    [4]=>
    string(14) "198.2.128.0/18"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`preg_match_all()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), and a slight modification of your regex:

```
php >  $regexIpAddress = '/ip4:([0-9.]+)/';
php >  preg_match_all($regexIpAddress, $spfreccord, $ip_match);
php >  var_dump($ip_match[1]);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "46.163.100.196"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "46.163.100.194"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "85.13.135.76"
}
php >
```

You don't need to match against `a-z`; it's not a valid part of an IP address, 4 or 6. Since you said you only want IPv4, I've excluded any matching of IPv6 addresses.

If you wanted to include IPv6 as well, you can do this:

```
php > $regexIpAddress = '/ip[46]:([0-9a-f.:]+)/';
php > preg_match_all($regexIpAddress, $spfreccord, $ip_match);
php > var_dump($ip_match[1]);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "46.163.100.196"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "46.163.100.194"
  [2]=>
  string(12) "85.13.135.76"
  [3]=>
  string(39) "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334"
}
```