# parsing invalid JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this little problem. I have this linux machine outputting this kind of JSON:

```
xxx.xx.x.x | SUCCESS => {
    "architecture": "amd64", 
    "blockdevice_fd0_size": 0, 
    "blockdevice_sda_model": "Virtual disk", 
    "blockdevice_sda_size": 21474836480, 
    "blockdevice_sda_vendor": "VMware", 
    "blockdevice_sr0_model": "VMware IDE CDR10", 
... etc ... etc...
}
```

As you can see, its not valid... I would like to parse this file as a json. I know I somehow have to get rid of these xxx.xx.x.x | SUCCESS`=> -lines.`Regexp` maybe? There are many entries in file. I tried strstr with for loop, some regexp and so. If someone could give me a pointer :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will have to remove the IP address using the regex. Then You can use PHP and simply explode the string ` and get your JSON from the resulting array.

```
$var = '192.168.1.1 | SUCCESS => {    "architecture": "amd64",      "lsbdistcodename": "wheezy",    "lsbdistdescription": "Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)",    "lsbdistid": "Debian",    "lsbdistrelease": "7.9",    "lsbmajdistrelease": "7",    "lsbminordistrelease": "9",     "memoryfree": "653.05 MB",    "memoryfree_mb": "653.05",    "memorysize": "1002.94 MB",    "memorysize_mb": "1002.94",     "operatingsystem": "Debian",    "operatingsystemmajrelease": "7",    "operatingsystemrelease": "7.9",    "os": {        "family": "Debian",        "lsb": {            "distcodename": "wheezy",            "distdescription": "Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)",            "distid": "Debian",            "distrelease": "7.9",            "majdistrelease": "7",            "minordistrelease": "9"        },        "name": "Debian",        "release": {            "full": "7.9",            "major": "7",            "minor": "9"        }    },    "osfamily": "Debian",    "partitions": {        "sda1": {            "filesystem": "LVM2_member",            "size": "41938944"        }    },     "physicalprocessorcount": 1,    "processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz",    "processorcount": 1,    "processors": {        "count": 1,        "models": [            "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz"        ],        "physicalcount": 1     },    "timezone": "EET",    "uniqueid": "007f0101",    "uptime": "360 days",    "uptime_days": 360,    "uptime_hours": 8644,    "uptime_seconds": 31119057,    "virtual": "vmware"}192.168.1.1 | SUCCESS => {    "architecture": "x86_64",       "is_virtual": true,    "kernel": "Linux",    "kernelmajversion": "3.10",    "kernelrelease": "3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64",    "kernelversion": "3.10.0",    "macaddress": "00:50:56:b1:c6:49",    "macaddress_eno16777984": "00:50:56:b1:c6:49",    "memoryfree": "1.58 GB",    "memoryfree_mb": "1617.09",    "memorysize": "1.80 GB",     "operatingsystemmajrelease": "7",    "operatingsystemrelease": "7.3.1611",    "os": {        "family": "RedHat",        "name": "CentOS",        "release": {            "full": "7.3.1611",            "major": "7",            "minor": "3"        }    },    "osfamily": "RedHat",    "partitions": {        "sda1": {            "filesystem": "xfs",            "mount": "/boot",            "size": "1024000",            "uuid": "e50a313f-98fa-4d7d-a40d-eb0c3b5f3ef5"        },        "sda2": {            "filesystem": "LVM2_member",            "size": "30423040"        }    },    "path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin",    "physicalprocessorcount": 1,    "processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz",    "processorcount": 1,    "processors": {        "count": 1,        "models": [            "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz"        ],        "physicalcount": 1    },     "timezone": "EET",    "uniqueid": "44d40600",    "uptime": "87 days",    "uptime_days": 87,    "uptime_hours": 2094,    "uptime_seconds": 7539660,    "virtual": "vmware"';

$pattern = '/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{2})?/';
$replacement = '';
$result =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $var); // Remove the IP address
echo "$result".PHP_EOL;
$arr = explode("| SUCCESS =>", $result); //Explode the string by the constant string

print_r($arr);
```

**Resulting Array**

```
The first element will be empty.
Array
(
    [0] =>  
    [1] =>  {    "architecture": "amd64",      "lsbdistcodename": "wheezy",    "lsbdistdescription": "Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)",    "lsbdistid": "Debian",    "lsbdistrelease": "7.9",    "lsbmajdistrelease": "7",    "lsbminordistrelease": "9",     "memoryfree": "653.05 MB",    "memoryfree_mb": "653.05",    "memorysize": "1002.94 MB",    "memorysize_mb": "1002.94",     "operatingsystem": "Debian",    "operatingsystemmajrelease": "7",    "operatingsystemrelease": "7.9",    "os": {        "family": "Debian",        "lsb": {            "distcodename": "wheezy",            "distdescription": "Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)",            "distid": "Debian",            "distrelease": "7.9",            "majdistrelease": "7",            "minordistrelease": "9"        },        "name": "Debian",        "release": {            "full": "7.9",            "major": "7",            "minor": "9"        }    },    "osfamily": "Debian",    "partitions": {        "sda1": {            "filesystem": "LVM2_member",            "size": "41938944"        }    },     "physicalprocessorcount": 1,    "processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz",    "processorcount": 1,    "processors": {        "count": 1,        "models": [            "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz"        ],        "physicalcount": 1     },    "timezone": "EET",    "uniqueid": "007f0101",    "uptime": "360 days",    "uptime_days": 360,    "uptime_hours": 8644,    "uptime_seconds": 31119057,    "virtual": "vmware"} 
    [2] =>  {    "architecture": "x86_64",       "is_virtual": true,    "kernel": "Linux",    "kernelmajversion": "3.10",    "kernelrelease": "3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64",    "kernelversion": "3.10.0",    "macaddress": "00:50:56:b1:c6:49",    "macaddress_eno16777984": "00:50:56:b1:c6:49",    "memoryfree": "1.58 GB",    "memoryfree_mb": "1617.09",    "memorysize": "1.80 GB",     "operatingsystemmajrelease": "7",    "operatingsystemrelease": "7.3.1611",    "os": {        "family": "RedHat",        "name": "CentOS",        "release": {            "full": "7.3.1611",            "major": "7",            "minor": "3"        }    },    "osfamily": "RedHat",    "partitions": {        "sda1": {            "filesystem": "xfs",            "mount": "/boot",            "size": "1024000",            "uuid": "e50a313f-98fa-4d7d-a40d-eb0c3b5f3ef5"        },        "sda2": {            "filesystem": "LVM2_member",            "size": "30423040"        }    },    "path": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin",    "physicalprocessorcount": 1,    "processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz",    "processorcount": 1,    "processors": {        "count": 1,        "models": [            "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz"        ],        "physicalcount": 1    },     "timezone": "EET",    "uniqueid": "44d40600",    "uptime": "87 days",    "uptime_days": 87,    "uptime_hours": 2094,    "uptime_seconds": 7539660,    "virtual": "vmware"
)
```

Note : This regex is for IPV4 addresses that I got from [IPV4 regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640920/regex-to-extract-only-ipv4-addresses-from-text). You can change the regex for removing the IPV6 addresses too.

[Working IDEONE Link](http://ideone.com/r2FpD5)

Comment: Yeah, I tried explode. Comes out like this :
Array
(
    [0] => xxx.x.x.x | SUCCESS 
    [1] =>  {
    "architecture": "amd64", 
    "blockdevice_fd0_size": 0, 
    "blockdevice_sda_model": "Virtual disk", 
    "blockdevice_sda_size": 21474836480,  etc.. etc..

xxx.xx.x.x | SUCCESS 
    [2] =>  {
    "architecture": "x86_64", 
    "blockdevice_fd0_size": 4096, 
    "blockdevice_sda_model": "Virtual disk",

But I cant output it to json. I need it like so, that I can use it as key : value :O.

Comment: @user7190476 Can you give me your complete input? So, that I can see how to process it.

Comment: @user7190476  Use JSON formatter http://jsonformatter.org/ to check the formatting and validity of your output JSON.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uNJ1ey7Q there u go. It's that kind of information. I took out some. In that paste, there is 2 entries

Comment: @user7190476 There are multiple JSON in this data.

Comment: Okay. I will try that out :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user7190476 I am looking for a viable solution. I think explode might not work.

Comment: @user7190476 Does `xxx.xx.x.x | SUCCESS => ` string will remain same value throughout or it will have different values ??

Comment: That xxx -value is an IP-address. So yes, there are diff values :)

Comment: @user7190476 Are you getting these values from a `array/map` structure??

Comment: actually it's Linux's Facter output, or so, I load it with file_get_contents so it's as a string.

Comment: @user7190476 So. the string will be having legit IP addresses??

Comment: Yeah. I think I should somehow get rid of those, cause they are breaking the json

Comment: Well thank u thank u thank u! :), now I got it workin! :))

Comment: @user7190476 Happy to help you out. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, ofc :). Sorry, I'm new in here

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ayush got a much prettier way

Will it be possible to jump to the first '{', and then just remove the contents before?

```
$findme   = '{';
$pos = strpos($json, $findme);
```

And then

```
$json= substr($json, $pos, 0);
```

Comment: the last parameter in the `substr` function should be omitted in order to get the whole json

Comment: I did that. But I think I need str_replace. I need to get rid of xxx.xx.x.x | SUCCESS => -lines. 

    "uptime_hours": 8644, 
    "uptime_seconds": 31119057, 
    "virtual": "vmware"
}
xxx.xx.x.x | SUCCESS => { <--- these gives me headeache
    "architecture": "x86_64", 
    "blockdevice_fd0_size": 4096, 
    "blockdevice_sda_model": "Virtual disk",

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression too:

```
// create the input json
$my_json = '212.68.0.4 | SUCCESS => { "architecture": "amd64", "blockdevice_fd0_size": 0, "blockdevice_sda_model": "Virtual disk", "blockdevice_sda_size": 21474836480, "blockdevice_sda_vendor": "VMware", "blockdevice_sr0_model": "VMware IDE CDR10"}';

// search for all chars before "{" and replace it with the bracket ({) using \\1
$output_json = preg_replace("/.*({)/", "\\1", $my_json);

// show the output result
echo $output_json;
```

Comment: Getting close, but still json_encode returns null and jsonlint is not accepting it :/

Comment: if you are using the json in the example, the last part is wrong, you could use something like this: 212.68.0.4 | SUCCESS => { "architecture": "amd64", "blockdevice_fd0_size": 0, "blockdevice_sda_model": "Virtual disk", "blockdevice_sda_size": 21474836480, "blockdevice_sda_vendor": "VMware", "blockdevice_sr0_model": "VMware IDE CDR10"}